# What can cause foamy urine other than protein?

Tags: urine, kidney, bladder-infection, urethra

I have got foamy urine for half a year and I recently feel obvious pain and burp after urine. However, when I use a urine test stick to test my urine (sold [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MD030YZ)), everything goes fine (no protein, no Leukocytes, no bilirubin, etc). I have been testing it for 3 days.

So I wanna ask what other situation can cause foamy urine and pain. Is it possible that it is bladder infection rather than kidney issue?

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Bel Marra Health](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/foamy-urine-causes/)

> Proteinuria: This is a condition in which protein is released in the
>   urine in high amounts. Protein is normally released in the urine but
>   in small amounts. When these levels become high, the urine can appear
>   foamy. This can be a sign of an impending kidney problem as the
>   kidneys are not filtering urine properly and thus release [too much
>   protein](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/proteinuria-protein-in-urine-treatment-with-statins-and-home-remedies-to-stop-chronic-kidney-disease/). Untreated high blood pressure and diabetes may contribute
>   to kidney filtration problems, along with other factors like toxins,
>   infections, or trauma to the kidneys.
>
> **Urinary tract infection:** When bacteria enter any part of the urinary tract system you may develop an infection. Along with pain,
>   higher urinary frequency and urgency, and burning while urinating,
>   your urine may appear foamy as well. You should see a doctor if you
>   begin to experience UTI symptoms because the earlier the treatment
>   begins the less of a risk of complications you will have.
>
> **Kidney disease:** Foamy urine can be a sign of kidney disease resulting from kidney stones or diabetes. A simple urine test will
>   determine whether you have kidney disease.
>
> **Preeclampsia during pregnancy:** Preeclampsia during pregnancy results in swollen legs, proteinuria, high blood pressure, and
>   headaches. This can be a fatal condition to both mother and fetus, and
>   all symptoms can worsen with its progression.
>
> **Vesicocolic fistula:** A fistula is an abnormal connection which in this case develops between the bladder and the colon. This allows air,
>   gas, and bacteria to travel into the bladder. Along with foamy urine,
>   a person with vesicocolic fistula will have frequent infections.
>   Symptoms may be similar to those of a UTI.
>
> **Rapid urination:** Urinating too quickly or forcing urine to come out can be responsible for its foamy appearance. This is because air
>   is introduced into the urine stream causing the bubbles. This type of
>   foam typically disappears within a few minutes.
>
> **Concentrated urine:** If you’re mildly dehydrated, the urine may become more concentrated, so it appears foamy. This can easily be
>   resolved by drinking more fluids.
>
> **Toilet cleaner:** Sometimes urine reacts with toilet cleaner which causes bubbles. If you’re unsure if your urine is foamy or whether
>   it’s the toilet cleaner causing it to foam, you can urinate in a
>   separate container that has not been treated with the cleaner and
>   watch for foam. Semen in urine: After sex, small amounts of semen are
>   left in the male urethra. This small amount won’t cause foamy urine
>   unless the bladder sphincter malfunctions, causing the semen to go
>   back into the bladder. In this case, urine will appear foamy.
>
> **Other causes:** Other causes of foamy urine include amyloidosis, cancer, chemical poisoning, diabetes, heart conditions like an
>   enlarged heart, high blood pressure, infections, kidney failure, liver
>   disease, lupus, rheumatoid arthritis, sarcoidosis, and sickle cell
>   anemia.

Comment: In the case of "chemical contamination", can the foamy urine last even after months the contamination ended? Which urine test could explain the bubbles, other than the 'total protein test'?